# SWIG typedef creates conflict across module boundary

Tags: c++, typedef, swig

I am writing a C# wrapper for the stepcode library (https://github.com/stepcode/stepcode) by using SWIG (version 4.1.1) as generator. The library is highly modularized, so there are situations where one wrapper module has to know about the declarations of another one.

Lets suppose I got the following structure in the native library:

- Module 1 (clstepcore): This module is the core module providing a class `Registry` and the following typedef:

  ```
  typedef void ( * CF_init )( Registry & ); //  pointer to creation initialization
  ```
- Module 2 (sdai_IFC4): This module uses the type of the first module, so SWIG provides the `%import` directive to include another module description file, but without generating any wrapper code for it 
  (see: https://www.swig.org/Doc4.1/Preprocessor.html#Preprocessor_nn3)

The code looks the following:

**clstepcore.i** (creates a wrapper for a creation callback and the registry constructor)

```
%module clstepcore
%{
#include "Registry.h"
%}
class Registry;
typedef void ( * CF_init )( Registry & ); //  pointer to creation initialization

class Registry {
public:
    Registry( CF_init initFunct );
    ~Registry();
};
```

**sdai_IFC4.i** (creates the wrapper for the actual creation function SchemaInit)

```
%module sdai_IFC4
%{
#include "schema.h"
%}

%import "clstepcore.i"
%callback("%s_cb");
void SchemaInit (Registry &);
%nocallback;
```

Unfortunately the generated C# for **both** modules contains the **exact** definition of the `CF_init` typedef, which resolves in a conflict between the two assemblies.

I've already tried things like `%ignore` but a found no working solution. Does anyone have built something like this an can provide my a hint? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot share a type across two modules. This means that all of your modules will have to have their own copy of `Registry` and these won't be compatible across the modules.

Your only solution is to rename this type in each module:

```
%rename(Registry_IFC4) Registry;
```

Comment: I can, actually the %import statement does exactly this. It makes the definitions "visible" but does not create a wrapper for it. But in contrast to the "Registry" type the function pointer typedef "CF_init" is duplicated.

Comment: In fact, it seems that it is possible to share type information across modules, but this is dependant on the target language. Have you tried renaming `CF_Init` in this case?